# I am trying to add onsubmit event to form, but don't have access to the form element

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to add an onsubmit event to a form of which I don't have direct access to the form tag, but can add code to the page. I would like to track virtual page views for Google Analytics by attaching the onsubmit event to the form. But the event is not firing, as the page is not showing up in GA. This is the code I have added to the page, below the form:

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("form").onsubmit = pageTracker._trackPageview('/virtual/form-submit/quote.html');
</script>
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Well, to start, `getElementsByTagName` returns an array.

Comment: What does the HTML of the form look like?

Comment: @Schmiddy, that is what the problem is.  OP needs to use getElementById or pick an element from getElementsByTagName.  The onsubmit attaches to the array as a new property.  You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> that might work.

Comment: @jonathan.cruz that's not necessary. `<script>` defaults to javascript in all browsers

Comment: Only strict XHTML (and you're properly passing it through an xml parser) requires the `type` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that the "function" you're assigning to the submit event is the return value of `pageTracker._trackPageview('/virtual/form-submit/quote.html');`

perhaps you meant to have that fire `onsubmit` and not immediately when the script loads? If so you should wrap that in an anonymous function

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form").onsubmit = function () { 
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/virtual/form-submit/quote.html');
};
```